# Can react state be used to extend an app bar height on load of a specific router link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styles, state, react-props

I currently have an application set up in react with react router and two 'page' components. I also have an app bar that is exported into the app.js file so that no matter what page is rendered in the router the app bar is consistent for each. The app bar height is 70px but I would like to make it so that the height is 128px when the homepage.js component is rendered, and if a user clicks back to another page the app bar height returns to 70px.

The app.js code:

```
function App () {
  return (
    <Router>
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <AppBar>
       <PageLink to="/about" name="About"/>
       </Appbar>
       <Switch>
        <Router exact path="/">
         <Home/>
        </Route>
       <Route path="/about">
        <About/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This is the appbar code (not wit all the styles, but it does include the two defined heights as shown below):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
standard: {
height: 72,
},
extended: {
height: 128,
},
})),

<MUIAppBar
id={id}
className={clsz(classes.container, classes[variant])}
position={position}
elevation={0}
style={style}
>

<Toolbar className={classes.toolbar} variant="dense">
<Link className={classes.title} to="/"></Link>
</Toolbar>
</MUIAppBar>
);
};

AppBar.defaulProps = {
id: "app-bar"
children: null,
style: {}
position: "static"
variant:"standard"
};

AppBar.propTypes = {
id: PropTypes.string,
children: PropTypes.node,
style: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
position: PropTypes.oneOf([
"fixed",
"absolute",
"sticky",
"static",
"relative",
]),
variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["standard", "extended])
};
```

After doing this and defining prop types for both versions, I can't think what to do next to render the extended variant as shown in the code above, would this be a state syntax and would it be placed in app.js to render for "/" path for the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a quick and maybe a dirty solution would be to wrap your `AppBar` component in a `Switch` router like this:

```
const AppBarRouter = () => {
  // Define all routes that need extended bar
  const extendedRoutes = [
    '/',
    'another-extended-route',
  ];
  return (
    <Switch>
      // Render all extended routes
      {extendedRoutes.map(path => {
        return <Route path={path} key={path} component={() => <AppBar extended />}
      })
      // The rest are not extended
      <Route component={AppBar}
    <Switch>
  )
}
```

Then you can render the `AppBarRouter` in your `App` component.

You can then extend this logic to work for your custom Toolbar components if you need different navigation links for different routes.